# как вывести нормальную строку?

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой. Пользователь вводит строку. По условию нельзя чтобы первый элемент строки был восклицательным знаком. Далее в строке должен быть обязательно восклицательный знак. Как скопировать содержимое строки до восклицательного знака (или обрезать строку). В моем соде при выводе "обрезанной строки" получается "кракозябра", как можно исправить?

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "rus");
    int CountSpace = 0, CountLit = 0, Index;
    char str [200] = "", str1[250] = "";
    do {
        cout << "Введите строку: "; //повторять ввод строки пока первый символ равен (!)
        gets_s(str);
        if(str[0] == '!')
        cout << "Первый символ строки <!>" << endl;
    } while (str[0] == '!');
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '!')
        {Index = i;
        break;}
    }
    cout << "\nПервый <!> встречается на " << Index+1 << " позиции";
    strncpy(str1, str, Index-1);
    cout << str1;
        system ("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что бы объявляете массив из **одного** нулевого символа

```
char str [] = ""
```

а потом читаете туда вообще неизвестно сколько

```
gets(str);
```

Этого уже достаточно для того, чтобы в программе могло происходить *все, что угодно*...

Но даже если бы у вас все было верно, и вы не пытались работать в невыделенной памяти, то учтите, что `strncpy` не записывает завершающий нулевой символ.

Вобщем, вот что вам нужно:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "rus");
    char str[300];
    do {
        cout << "Введите строку: "; //повторять ввод строки пока первый символ равен (!)
        gets_s(str,300);
        if(str[0] == '!')
            cout << "Первый символ строки <!>" << endl;
    } while (str[0] == '!');
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '!')
        {
            str[i] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << str << endl;
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: а как лучше объявить?)

Comment: @Trapezant например вот так char str[200];

Comment: Указать размер, и использовать не `gets` - все, ее уже нет в новых стандартах - а хотя бы `gets_s`. Но у вас же стоит тэг C++ - так почему бы не работать со строками `string`?

Comment: и только в этом проблема?

Comment: Две проблемы я указал в ответе. Те, которые просто бросались в глаза. Не скажу, что там нет других - так внимательно я не смотрел. Исправите эти, а там видно будет...

Comment: ну просто в условии массив char, без использования string

Comment: Ну тогда указывайте его размер заранее, и читайте с помощью `gets_s`, чтоб не прочесть лишнего.

Comment: поменял и все равно мусор после копирования выводит

Comment: Как поменяли? Покажите.

Comment: отредактированный код выше

Comment: **НЕ МЕНЯЙТЕ КОД В ВОПРОСЕ!** Иначе непонятно, с чего это я такой кретин, что указываю на какие-то ошибки, которых у вас вовсе нет? Вобщем, забирайте в ответе (см. **дополненный**, а не **измененный** ответ) то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Я работаю с кириллицей, а в программе закоментирована строка с подключением кириллицы, это так и нужно?

Comment: Нет, это я у себя отключаю.